# how to overcome this ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

in the following code, I got the errors

```
n = 101                # Number of grid points
P = np.zeros((n, n))
xmin, xmax = 0.0, 1.0     # limits in the x direction
ymin, ymax = -0.5, 0.5

x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, nx)
y = np.linspace(ymin, ymax, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y, indexing='ij')
a = ((D/(dx*dx))-(X-Y*Y)/(2*dx))
b = (2+X-4*D/(dx*dx))
c = ((D/(dx*dx))-(Y+X*Y)/(2*dx))
d = ((D/(dx*dx))+(Y+X*Y)/(2*dx))
e = ((D/(dx*dx))+(X-Y*Y)/(2*dx))

### boundary conditions
for i in range(len(P)):

     P[i, 0] = 0               # Left boundary
     P[i, -1] = 0                     # Right boundary
     P[0, i] = 0         # Lower boudary
     P[-1, i] = 0                    
f = 0.
w = 1.2

resid_crit = 1.0e-6

# Arbitrary value at the begining, higher than resid_crit
resid_ave = 100.

count = 0

while resid_ave > resid_crit:

    # Set at 0 so we can sum it up later
    resid_ave = 0.


    # Set count for points in checker-boarding
    cnt_points = 0

    # Loop over internal points only
    for i in range(1, n - 1):
        for j in range(1, n - 1):

            # Checker-boarding
            if ((i + j) % 2) == count % 2:
                # Residual
                residual = a[i,j] * P[i - 1, j] + b[i,j] * P[i, j] + c[i,j] * P[i, j - 1] + d[i,j] * P[i, j + 1] + e * P[
                    i+1, j] - f

                # Update psi value

                P[i, j] += -w * residual / b[i,j]

                # Update resid_ave as a sum of residuals
                resid_ave += abs(residual)


                cnt_points += 1

    #  Get average residual
    resid_ave = resid_ave / cnt_points

    # Print every 1000-dth residual
    if count % 1000 == 0:
        print("Residual: %.7f" % resid_ave)
        #print("Residual: ", resid_ave)

    # Count iterations
    count = count + 1
```

Output showing:

```
TypeError: only size-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gitsa\PycharmProjects\sagarPy1\SKtest.py", line 89, in <module>
    P[i, j] += -w * residual / b[i,j]
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

Comment: I think this means that `w` is an array. You need to index the array to get a single number.

Comment: **w** is a real number whose value is 1.2

Comment: Add `print(w, residual, b[i,j])` One of those should be an array.

Comment: @Barmar please look at the edited python code

Comment: Why don't you want to perform basic debugging by looking at the values of all the variables in the statement that gets the error?

Comment: I am new to python and don't know what this errors means

Comment: `P[i, j]` is an element of the `P` array. It can only contain a single value. But `-w * residual / b[i,j]` is evaluating to an array, not a single value. So some part of that must also be an array.

Comment: So print `w`, `residual`, and `b[i, j]` to see what they each contain.

Comment: So you are new to python, and are using code written by someone else.  Good recipe for errors if you don't follow their intentions exactly (or use wrong inputs).

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to python, then you have borrowed code written by someone who has experience.  But we don't know what what you changed - code or inputs.

The code of the error is `P[i,j]` a single element of a 2d array.  The RHS of the `*=` must be an array (1 or 2d) to produce this error.

`w` is scalar, a number.  `b[i,j]` is an element of a 2d array.  So the problem is with `residual`.

In the `residual` calculation, `f` is also scalar.  Other terms are elements of 2d arrays.  But `e` looks like a caclulation from `X` and `Y` which are 2d `meshgrid` results.

Again, we don't know the knowledge or intention of this code writer.  Maybe someone wrote `e` instead of `e[i,j]`.